# If an instance of the application is already running, call a method within the already running instance

Tags: c#, winforms, ipc

I have an application that consists of a system tray notifyIcon and its context menu. In the program.cs code, I use a Mutex to check if an instance of the program is already running before starting a new one.  Currently, if one is already running, the new instance just exits right there.  Instead, when the user tries to start a new instance of the application, I'd like it to trigger the context menu of the notifyIcon in the running instance.  Is there a way to do this?  Is there a good way to call a method in an already running process and tell it to open the menu?

I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32908/C-Single-Instance-App-With-the-Ability-To-Restore) interesting article, which refers  to [this](http://sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html) article.  Both have some very promising code on how to do basically what I want. However, their code overrides the WndProc method, which I know little about.  When I used their code, I got the error that "no suitable method found to override", which  I gather is because my main code for the notifyIcon and context menu, has no actual form, and from my limited understanding from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc(v=vs.110).aspx), WndProc is a method of an actual form.

Am I understanding their solutions and the error I got correctly?  If not please, explain, I'm happy to learn.  If I am understanding, then is there a way to do this that allows me to just trigger a context menu of a notifyIcon without having to have an actual form?

Note: For the record, my program.cs follows the exact format of the one in the second link provided.

As mentioned, my program.cs is nearly identical to the one in the second link, but here it is just to be clear:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Context_Menu
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>

        static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "{41264ee37e7688d64250ffb50dc681d2}");

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
            {
                Application.Run(new PCMLnotifyIcon());
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
            else
            {
                // send our Win32 message to make the currently running instance
                // jump on top of all the other windows
                NativeMethods.PostMessage(
                    (IntPtr)NativeMethods.HWND_BROADCAST,
                    NativeMethods.WM_SHOWME,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    IntPtr.Zero);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My NativeMethods class is identical to the one in the link as well, like so:

```
internal class NativeMethods {
    public const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;
    public static readonly int WM_SHOWME = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_SHOWME");
    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);
    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string message);
}
```

And finally, PCMLNotifyIcon is based heavily on [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/627796/Doing-a-NotifyIcon-program-the-right-way) guide, and therefore is just a notifyIcon without an accompanying form.  Heres a snippet showing where I dropped the code from the second link:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Context_Menu
{
    class PCMLnotifyIcon : ApplicationContext
    {  
        private NotifyIcon niIcon;
        private ContextMenuStrip cmsMenu;
        private ToolStripMenuItem tsmiUpdate;
        private ToolStripSeparator tssOne;
        private ToolStripMenuItem tsmiQuickAdd;
        private ToolStripSeparator tssTwo;
        private ToolStripSeparator tssThree;
        private ToolStripMenuItem tsmiSettings;
        private ToolStripMenuItem tsmiAbout;
        private ToolStripMenuItem tsmiFeedback;
        private ToolStripMenuItem tsmiExit;

        public PCMLnotifyIcon()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == NativeMethods.WM_SHOWME)
            {
                ShowMe();
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
```

And the error given, as mentioned above I suspect is because of the lack of a form: Error   1

> 'Context_Menu.PCMLnotifyIcon.WndProc(ref
>   System.Windows.Forms.Message)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: Take your pick of IPC.  _"I got the error"_ - post your code please. See [mcve]

Comment: _"because my main code for the notifyIcon and context menu, has no actual form"_ - are you using the `NotifyIcon` without it being embedded in a `Form`?

Comment: I am indeed.  I am using the method detailed here. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/627796/Doing-a-NotifyIcon-program-the-right-way
The reason is that the program has no need for a form upon starting.  Just the notifyIcon and its menu.

Comment: I updated the question with code to show.  Like I mentioned in the original question, the code is virtually unchanged from the second link, the problem seems to be in that I have no actual form.  So I'm assuming that means I'll need to find an entirely different way of going about this?

Answer (score 0):

I would offer some code, but I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish. Instead, I'll see if I can point you in the right direction :) I have used an IPC channel with great success in a very similar instance. However, it seems this has ben deprecated in favor of WCF. It doesn't look too bad though. You can use named pipes in place of TCP and it should be very performant. I think you'll find this more reliable than window messaging, which is clunky at best. You can pass rather large and complex payloads easily and natively.

Check out this article: https://gorillacoding.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/using-wcf-for-inter-process-communication/

Here's another example you may find useful: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2013/12/inter-process-communication-using-wcf.html

EDIT: as a bonus, you may be able to drop the mutex in favor of testing for the existence of the named pipe

Comment: Ah yes _.NET Remoting_. I agree as a straight-up comms choice (even for local computer) it's deprecated. It is useful to this day though for communication to child `AppDomain`s in a sandboxed plug-in system but I  digress :)   By the way "IPC" just refers to the feature of one program talking to another.  It doesn't actually refer to any particular transport; technology or protocol.  .NET Remoting _is an IPC_ but it isn't _the IPC_.

Comment: _"I'm not sure where MSMQ entered the picture "_ - oh no that's my bad. I saw _"than window messaging"_ and thought MSMQ.  I see now OP is posting messages over Windows Message Pump.  Sorry buddy

Comment: Yes, I could have been more specific re IPC as well, this is what I was referencing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.ipc.ipcchannel.aspx

Comment: Yes Microsoft confused many people with that "IPC" name. They mean named-pipes.  Lowry mentioned it in his [awesome book](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-WCF-Services-Mastering-AppFabric/dp/0596805489/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1455759846&sr=8-2&keywords=programming+wcf). :P

Comment: I'd still keep the mutex... pipes are great, just not so great for ensuring uniqueness without writing some (potentially lots?) of scaffolding code...

Answer (score 0):

I hate to flip the paradigm around, but why did you not choose to use something like pipes? Would have been much easier to do, IMHO. Moving on to the main issue on hand: after `ShowMe();`, put a `return`. Like this:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == NativeMethods.WM_SHOWME)
    {
        ShowMe();
        return;  // <-- right here!
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not sure I see what this will help.  However, I gave it a try, but I'm still getting the problem of WndProc not actually being a method of ApplicationContext which is what my class is derived from.  I think that method is only available if you have an actual form.  Unless I'm misunderstanding you here.